# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb3'

Tags: laravel

I wanted to make migrate and got this error. Now I see it everywhere, + it points to a section of code(I changed the base encoding)

```
class Category extends Model
{
   
  public static function children($parent=null) {
    return Category::where('parent_id',$parent)->orderBy('name')->get();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something happened in the configuration, the database encoding changed there

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).